# jooq-codegen-maven plugin and JDK9 compilation error

Tags: maven, jooq, java-9

I just upgraded my project form JDK8 to JDK9. I use JOOQ library version 3.9.5. I now see this error when I compile.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.5:generate (default) on project myproject-db-model: Execution default of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.5:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.5:generate: javax/xml/bind/JAXB
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.9.5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq-codegen-maven/3.9.5/jooq-codegen-maven-3.9.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.1.1/postgresql-42.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/Workspace/MyProjects/myproject/model/dbms-strategies/target/myproject-dbms-strategies-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.11/logback-core-1.1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.25/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.5.20/tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.5.20/tomcat-juli-8.5.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.0.Final/jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.1.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/5.0.12.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.11.7.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.7.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq/3.9.5/jooq-3.9.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq-meta/3.9.5/jooq-meta-3.9.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[39] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[40] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[41] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[42] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[43] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.1.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[44] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[45] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar
[ERROR] urls[46] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar
[ERROR] urls[47] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[48] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-archaius/1.1.5.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-archaius-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[49] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/netflix/archaius/archaius-core/0.7.4/archaius-core-0.7.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[50] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.8/commons-configuration-1.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[51] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[52] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.3/hystrix-core-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[53] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.1.1/rxjava-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[54] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.7/HdrHistogram-2.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[55] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-metrics-event-stream/1.5.3/hystrix-metrics-event-stream-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[56] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-javanica/1.5.3/hystrix-javanica-1.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[57] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[58] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.1/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[59] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[60] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[61] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[62] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.20/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[63] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.20/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[64] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.20/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar
[ERROR] urls[65] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.3.5.Final/hibernate-validator-5.3.5.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[66] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[67] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.1/classmate-1.3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[68] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[69] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[70] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[71] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[72] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[73] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.2.1.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[74] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[75] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[76] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.10/jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[77] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[78] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.10/jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[79] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.8.10/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[80] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.8.10/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[81] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr353/2.8.10/jackson-datatype-jsr353-2.8.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[82] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.1/javax.json-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[83] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/javax/json/javax.json-api/1.1/javax.json-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[84] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.1/gson-2.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[85] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/jayway/jsonpath/json-path/2.2.0/json-path-2.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[86] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/net/minidev/json-smart/2.2.1/json-smart-2.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[87] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/net/minidev/accessors-smart/1.1/accessors-smart-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[88] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/1.5.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[89] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.7/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[90] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.7/log4j-api-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[91] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.7/log4j-core-2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[92] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.25/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[93] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
[ERROR] urls[94] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/javax0/immutator/1.0.1/immutator-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[95] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/javax0/djcproxy/2.0.3/djcproxy-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[96] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/javax0/jscc/1.0.1/jscc-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[97] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/javax0/jscglib/1.0.1/jscglib-1.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[98] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-4.5.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[99] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[100] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[101] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/22.0/guava-22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[102] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[103] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.0.18/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar
[ERROR] urls[104] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[105] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar
[ERROR] urls[106] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jool/0.9.12/jool-0.9.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[107] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/joor/0.9.6/joor-0.9.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[108] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/com/github/ben-manes/caffeine/caffeine/2.3.5/caffeine-2.3.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[109] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq-codegen/3.9.5/jooq-codegen-3.9.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[110] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/backport-util-concurrent/backport-util-concurrent/3.1/backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[111] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.11/plexus-interpolation-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[112] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
[ERROR] urls[113] = file:/Users/jeanvaljean/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: javax.xml.bind.JAXB
```

In the build section I have

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/database.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>src/main/resources/database.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${flyway.version}</version>

            <!-- Note that we're executing the Flyway plugin in the "generate-sources" phase -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>migrate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <!-- Note that we need to prefix the db/migration path with filesystem: to prevent Flyway
                 from looking for our migration scripts only on the classpath -->
            <configuration>
                <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                <url>${db.url}</url>
                <user>${db.username}</user>
                <password>${db.password}</password>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${org.jooq.version}</version>

            <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!--<execution>-->
                <!--<goals>-->
                <!--<goal>generate</goal>-->
                <!--</goals>-->
                <!--</execution>-->
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                    <url>${db.url}</url>
                    <user>${db.username}</user>
                    <password>${db.password}</password>
                </jdbc>

                <generator>
                    <name>org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator</name>
                    <strategy>
                        <name>com.myproject.dbms.jooq.conf.RemoveColumnPrefixDatabaseStrategy</name>
                    </strategy>

                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <!--force generating id'sfor everything in public schema, that has an 'id' field-->
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes></excludes>

                        <schemata>
                            <schema>
                                <inputSchema>commons</inputSchema>
                            </schema>
                        </schemata>

                        <unsignedTypes>false</unsignedTypes>

                        <customTypes>
                            <customType>
                                <name>Json</name>
                                <type>com.google.gson.JsonElement</type>
                                <binding>com.myproject.dbms.jooq.databinding.PostgresJSONGsonBinding</binding>
                            </customType>
                        </customTypes>
                        <forcedTypes>
                            <forcedType>
                                <name>Json</name>
                                <types>json</types>
                            </forcedType>
                            <forcedType>
                                <name>NUMERIC(8,2)</name>
                                <expression>shop.localized_money.lm_amount</expression>
                                <types>.*</types>
                            </forcedType>
                        </forcedTypes>

                      <generate>
                        <!--<javaTimeTypes/>-->
                        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                        <relations>true</relations>
                        <generatedAnnotation>false</generatedAnnotation>
                        <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                        <records>true</records>
                        <interfaces>false</interfaces>
                        <pojos>true</pojos>
                        <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
                        <daos>false</daos>
                        <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
                        <springAnnotations>true</springAnnotations>
                        <validationAnnotations>true</validationAnnotations>
                        <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
                        <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
                        <pojosEqualsAndHashCode>true</pojosEqualsAndHashCode>
                        <globalUDTReferences>true</globalUDTReferences>
                    </generate>

                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.myproject.model.jooq</packageName>
                        <!--<directory>src/main/java</directory>-->
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any idea? May it be an old transitive dependency in the jOOQ plugin? Maybe [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw) page may help.

Comment: You can try their latest version as well 
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.5</version>
</dependency>`...just to confirm and reproduce.

Comment: The solution to this could probably be a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221811/1746118). You can try `<compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
        </compilerArgs>` in maven-compiler-plugin to instantly check for it. Though the long term solution is to move away.

Comment: @nullpointer I tried with no changes

Comment: It's not the compiler lacking the module, but the JVM running the JOOQ plugin.

Comment: @JeanValjean If updating the plugin  and `--add-modules` didn't work for you. you can possibly try out Nicolai's answer about the JVM config as well.

Comment: @JeanValjean Just to keep a track this could be updated at https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6477 if there suggested solution doesn't work.

Comment: @nullpointer correct, once I will find a solution I will post a reply, altough Lukas Edler (jOOQ mantainer) have already seen this SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Version 3.10.0 - September 29, 2017](https://www.jooq.org/notes#3.10.0)

Just to mark this up to the date, you can now use `JOOQ` library version `3.10.0`.

> ..is the first release that is formally integration tested with Java 9
>   along with the existing integration tests for Java 6/7 and for Java 8.
>   To use *jOOQ with Java 9 use the Java 8 distribution which has not yet
>   been modularised, but contains Automatic-Module-Name* specification to
>   be forward compatible with future, modularised jOOQ distributions.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently the jooq-codegen-maven plugin uses the JAXB API, which is found in [the Java EE module *java.xml.bind*](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html). However, [Java EE modules are not resolved by default](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules) (and also deprecated), which explains why the JVM complains that it can't find `JAXBException`.

To clarify: It's the JVM running the Maven process that is missing the dependency, **not** the compilation it launches!

The short term fix is to add the dependency manually with `--add-modules` **to the JVM executing the plugin**:

- If the plugin allows forking (i.e. it can be executed in another JVM than the one running the Maven process), you might be able to add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to it in your POM. A quick search suggest that that might not be possible.
- Otherwise you need to configure the JVM running the Maven process, which you can do with [the poorly documented `.mvn/jvm.config` file](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html#JVM_and_Command_Line_Options). Simply add such a file to the directory from which you launch the build (likely the one containing your POM) and put `--add-modules java.xml.bind` in there. (Unfortunate side effect: You can no longer build with Java 8.)

For a little more details on the second approach, check [this newsletter that I wrote](https://medium.com/codefx-weekly/reflective-access-maven-on-java-9-and-speeding-through-the-night-a71ab23b6364#d87d).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084751/how-to-express-dependency-in-maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9/46086920#46086920) or [java-9-add-modules-only-on-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220810/java-9-add-modules-only-on-compilation/46221811#46221811) ? Also one of the comments on the question reads that the compiler args didn't help OP.

Comment: I edited my answer to address the actual problem - this is not about the compiler missing the module, but the JVM running the JOOQ plugin. I don't think we had such a question yet (not sure, though).

Comment: The `javax.xml.bind` is the same package that the other two questions point to. Anyway, let's wait for the OP to try out the JVM config solution proposed by you. :)

Comment: I just saw that I forgot to remove parts of my old answer, which was confusing. Re the package, yes it's the same one, but it's an entirely different step of the process. The error does not indicate that the application or any of its dependencies need _java.xml.bind_, so adding it to compilation (or testing) doesn't help. It's "only" the build process, which needs that module.

Comment: By the way [jOOQ#5477](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6477) states the workaround as `--add-modules` only.

Comment: @LukasEder the workaround `--add-modules` shall work according to the link?

Comment: @nullpointer you are right, just ``--add-modules`` removes that problem but shows up this message "``Execution default-testCompile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile failed. NoSuchElementException"``. I tried to use Maven option `-DskipTests` but then I get `Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile failed. NoSuchElementException`. I'm not sure that it solves the issue.

Comment: @nullpointer: Yes it solves this particular problem. There might be more problems. @JeanValjean, I suggest creating a new question about the `NoSuchElementException`, I think it's not related.

Comment: @LukasEder maybe you are right. I'm trying all the conbinations, included those explained by Nicolai in his newsletter, but nothing change. I may still have made a mistake, but...

Comment: It looks like you are facing a sequence of problems and that this answer only fixes the first. Assuming the `jvm.config` gets you passed the code generation, you should consider that particular problem fixed and move on to the next (compilation), for which you might want to open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about building, this work for me to build unsing `JDK 11 Hotspot` an `Sping-Boot 2.0.3.RELEASE` target is `Jre 8`.

```
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
              <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
                </dependency>
                ...
              </dependencies>
              ...
            </plugin>
```