# JUnit 5, Java 9 and Gradle: How to pass --add-modules?

Tags: gradle, java-9, junit5

I want to migrate from Java 8 to Java 9. When running my tests I get a CNFE regarding javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext. Therefore, "--add-modules java.xml.bind" seems to be required. I tried to extend my GRADLE_OPTS env variable, but the error remains. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look at [How to express dependency in maven on java ee features for transition to Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46084751/how-to-express-dependency-in-maven-on-java-ee-features-for-transition-to-java-9/46086920#46086920) ? Could you detail your setup otherwise please.

Comment: It's a runtime failure, and not a compilation issue. I'm using Kotlin (not Java) and Spring Boot. @nullpointer: Does it mean, that I've only to adapt the 2nd part of your answer?

Comment: Yes, just the test execution phase, in that case, should be the change required for you.

Comment: To add to @nullpointer's comment. Java SE has deprecated the java.xml.bind module for removal. This means that `--add-modules java.xml.bind` is a short term workaround and you'll have to re-visit it. Better to move to the standalone API/implementation (javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0 and org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Alan Bateman, I added the following lines to `build.gradle` so that `gradle bootRun` also works:

```
runtime('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0', 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the five basic steps while migrating as stated in the [gradle-building java9 modules](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/) which are:-

> When converting a java-library project to produce a Java 9 module,
>   there are five changes you should to make to your project.
>
> - Add a `module-info.java` describing the module.
> - Modify the `compileJava` task to produce a module.
> - Modify the `compileTestJava` task to locally alter the module.
> - Modify the `test` task to consume the locally altered module.
> - (Optional) Add `Automatic-Module-Name` manifest entries for all other projects.

---

In your use case, you need to ensure that the

```
compileTestJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath, 
            '--add-modules', 'org.junit.jupiter.api',  // junit5 automatic module specific
            '--add-modules', 'java.xml.bind', // jaxb specific
            '--add-reads', "$moduleName=org.junit.jupiter.api", // allow junit to read your module
            '--patch-module', "$moduleName=" + files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs).asPath, // add test source files to your module

        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

and then for executing the test, you would need not to udpate the `test` task as

```
test {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        jvmArgs = [
            '--module-path', classpath.asPath, 
            '--add-modules', 'ALL-MODULE-PATH', // to resolve all module in the module path to be accessed by gradle test runner
            '--add-reads', "$moduleName=org.junit.jupiter.api", 
            '--patch-module', "$moduleName=" + files(sourceSets.test.java.outputDir).asPath, 
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

***Note***: For a long-term solution though I would also suggest you follow the important point mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086920/1746118) as well.