# gradle precompile SpringSource project failed

Tags: java, spring, gradle, intellij-idea

I just cloned the Spring Source from `git://github.com/SpringSource/Spring-framework.git`, and I want to import it into my idea.
According to the file `import-into-idea.md`, I ran the command: `./gradlew :spring-oxm:compileTestJava`,but it was failed with an exception: 
[image]

Would someone tell me why this happen? and how to resolve..Thanks very much!

Comment: What JDK do you use to run gradle task? If it's 9 or 10 you need to add "--add-modules" to compile task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991022/junit-5-java-9-and-gradle-how-to-pass-add-modules

Comment: @ y.bedrov At first I used 9, and later I changed to 8, but it didn't help.I finally import the project into my idea without precompile :)