# Sonar scanner with Maven and JDK 11

Tags: sonarqube, maven-3, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, java-11

I can make Sonar scanner work with OpenJDK 8 but not with OpenJDK 11.

The Maven command used is:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json -P ci
```

The build fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project framework-bio: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Is Sonar Scanner expected to work with JDK 11?

Comment: or you could have [explicitly added the `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086920/1746118) to your dependencies ?

Comment: Yes indeed. But I don't like the idea of adding a dependency to my project just because its code analyzer misses it.

Comment: well, surely a plus there unless you end up realizing the class was of some importance to your project... and if it wasn't, it shouldn't have been there at the first place :)

Comment: I am not sure to understand your comment.
I am 100% sure that my project does not need javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api, only the plugin that is downloaded by Sonar scanner does.

Comment: @nullpointer the module does not exist any longer in JDK11

Comment: @SebastianThees Yes I know, hence the use of the word *"explicitly"* in my previous comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found https://github.com/sonargraph/sonar-sonargraph-integration/issues/14

The issue is coming from SonarQube plugin named sonar-sonargraph-integration.
I uninstalled the plugin from SonarQube server and the issue went away.